# How can I execute some code when a Blazor WASM (standalone) app starts?

Tags: blazor

I'd need to call my overridden GetAuthenticationStateAsync once, when the app starts. Online I found example using OnInitializedAsync but this would be called at every component initialization.

I wonder which are the methods I could override for app lifecycle.

Comment: App.razor `OnInitializedAsync `

Comment: Maybe OnAfterRender of the App component, and use the firstRender flag?